# ObjectDatasource Update Method - with Generic object parameter which contains sub object is not working

Tags: c#, gridview, parameters, objectdatasource, business-logic

**Entities**

```
public class Calculation
{
    public int UniqueID { get; set; }
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public Operation Operation { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDateTime { get; set; }
}

 public class Operation
{
    public int OperationID { get; set; }
    public string OperationName { get; set; }
}
```

**Business Logic Layer**

```
public bool UpdateCalculation(Calculation calcObject)
    {
        bool returnVal = false;
        try
        {
            if (GetCalculationByID(calcObject) != null)
            {
                returnVal = calcDAL.UpdateCalculation(calcObject);
                if (returnVal)
                    return returnVal;
                else
                    throw new ApplicationException(ResourceHelper.GetErrorResourceValue("MSG003"));
            }
            else
                throw new ApplicationException(ResourceHelper.GetErrorResourceValue("MSG006"));
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            LoggingHelper.WriteLog(exp, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), TraceEventType.Error);
            throw exp;
        }
    }
```

**Data Access Layer:**

```
public bool UpdateCalculation(Calculation calcObject)
    {
        try
        {
            object[] parameters = new object[5];
            parameters.SetValue(calcObject.UniqueID, 0);
            parameters.SetValue(calcObject.Value1, 1);
            parameters.SetValue(calcObject.Value2, 2);
            parameters.SetValue(calcObject.Result, 3);
            parameters.SetValue(calcObject.Operation.OperationID, 4);
            int returnVal = _db.ExecuteNonQuery(ResourceHelper.GetSpResourceValue("UPD_CALC"), parameters);
            if (returnVal > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Utilities.LoggingHelper.WriteLog(exp, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), TraceEventType.Error);
            throw exp;
        }
    }
```

I am using the Enterprise Library 5.0 to perform the DB operation from DAL.

The below code shows how the objects are binded to the HTML in Web project.

**Website**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataSourceID="CalculationDS" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted"
        OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" 
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="UniqueID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UniqueID" HeaderText="UniqueID" 
                SortExpression="UniqueID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Value1" HeaderText="Value1" 
                SortExpression="Value1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Value2" HeaderText="Value2" 
                SortExpression="Value2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Result" HeaderText="Result" 
                SortExpression="Result" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Operation" 
                SortExpression="OperationName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="drpOperations" runat="server" DataSourceID="OperationDS" 
                        DataTextField="OperationName" DataValueField="OperationID" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Operation.OperationID") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="OperationDS" runat="server" 
                        SelectMethod="GetAllOperations" TypeName="SampleBLL.OperationBLL">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="OperationName" Name="sortExpression" 
                                Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Ascending" Name="sortDirection" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("Operation.OperationName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EntryDateTime" HeaderText="EntryDateTime" 
                SortExpression="EntryDateTime" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CalculationDS" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="SampleEntities.Calculation"
        DeleteMethod="DeleteCalculation" InsertMethod="InsertCalculation" SelectMethod="GetAllCalculations"
        TypeName="SampleBLL.CalculationBLL" UpdateMethod="UpdateCalculation" OnSelecting="CalculationDS_Selecting"
        OnUpdating="CalculationDS_Updating">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" DefaultValue="UniqueID" Name="sortExpression"
                PropertyName="SortExpression" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="sortDirection" PropertyName="SortDirection"
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

When i try to edit the row and submit, the OPERATION column in the CALCULATION object is NULL in the DAL when i read the calculation object Operation ID its NULL.

I have tried to read the value from the CalculationDs (ObjectDatasource) Updating event
and GridView Updating event but no use.

The OPERATION object column is not automatically mapped to the GridView column.

Thanks in advance. if you got solution for this update to work.. !!:(